# terraform v0.11 - invalid or unknown key: efs_volume_configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

just want to ask if you have any idea on whats missing here on the terraform code block:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                   = "${lower(var.MY_FAMILY_ID)}-${lower(var.TYPE)}}-efs"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = var.CPU
  memory                   = var.MEMORY
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.ecs_template.rendered
  execution_role_arn       = data.iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = data.iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  

volume {
      name  = "my-volume"
      efs_volume_configuration {
        file_system_id = data.aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
        root_directory          = "/pogi"
      }
  }
}
```

The Terraform code above is verified working on Terraform v0.14 however when trying to use on Terraform v0.11 it gives this message.

```
Error: aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition: volume.0: invalid or unknown key: efs_volume_configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`efs_volume_configuration` has been added to [v2.68.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v2.68.0/CHANGELOG.md) of AWS provider. Thus you must [upgrade](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-versioning#upgrade-the-aws-provider-version) your AWS provider to at least that version.

Comment: worked! thanks @Marcin!